# Mostrar registros de formulario en mismo archivo de validación en PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, formularios

Estoy trabajando sobre un formulario de HTML del cual envió los valores por método post a mi siguiente archivo PHP llamado **insertar.php*, por lo cual una vez insertado necesito que el mismo archivo muestra en estructura HTML los datos insertados pero estoy teniendo error en la condición de la consulta y esta se cicla constantemente por ser un **window.location**.

Alguna solución para mostrar los datos validados anteriormente en el mismo archivo insertar.php???

Este es mi código **insertar.php**

```
<?php
include ("conn.php");

$valor1= $_POST['valor1'];
$valor2= $_POST['valor2'];
$valor3= $_POST['valor3'];


$insertar = "INSERT INTO reportes (valor1, valor2, valor3) VALUES ('$valor1', '$valor2', '$valor3')";

$resultado = mysqli_query($mysqli, $insertar);
if($resultado){
echo"<script>alert('Reporte registrado');
window.location.href='insertar.php'</script>"; //Intenté probar con header('Location: insertar.php'); y tampoco es funcional...
}else{
echo"<script>alert('ERROR');
window.history.go(-1)</script>";
}
?>


   <html>
    <body>
     <h2> Hola, estas son tus respuestas</h2>
     <h2>Respuesta 1: <?php echo $valor1;?></h2>
     <h2>Respuesta 2: <?php echo $valor2;?></h2>
     <h2>Respuesta 3: <?php echo $valor3;?></h2>
    </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que es mas conveniente si separas tu código insertar.php en otro archivo, con los archivos ya separados te funcionaria el `window.location.href='repuestas.php`

Crea un archivo nuevo de php, en este caso yo le he puesto repuestas.php, allí simplemente vas realizar una consulta a tu base de datos con lo que acabaste de insertar, de modo que
cuando insertar.php se ejecute, este te redirigirá con `window.location.href='repuestas.php` a repuestas.php donde habrá una consulta a la base de datos

[aquí puedes ver como realizar esa consulta en caso que no tengas idea](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.msql-fetch-array)